# ASP.net mvc 2 solution folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

What is the best way to organize a MVC2 web project (as complex as stackoverflow)?
should i have everything in one project?
if not, how should i separate the projects and folders?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119388/how-to-customize-directory-structure-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127886/what-is-the-best-practice-for-view-file-directory-structure-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002220/changing-asp-net-mvc-default-folder-structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178715/mvc-folder-structure-for-project-with-multiple-themes-skin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433192/c-mvc-folder-structure-where-to-put-classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540882/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178398/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637391/where-should-a-viewmodel-sit-in-the-directory-structure-of-an-asp-net-mvc-applica http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715/asp-net-mvc-subfolders http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180704/question-about-mvc-folder-structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *best way*. There are *good* and *bad* ways. Having everything in the same project is definitely not a good way. Big projects should be separated in layers and each layer usually goes into a different assembly so that it can be reused in other projects. For example you could have Models, Data Access, Business Logic, Web.

Jeffrey Palermo has a series of posts about the [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) which is worth reading.

From performance standpoint it is considered a good practice to have less bigger assemblies than many smaller assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at MVC Areas in MVC 2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx

This is one way to organise code in larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a new ASP.NET MVC Project and then add a couple of more projects to your solution. I usually end up with:

```
MyProject
MyProject.Data
MyProject.Test
```

I normally put the generated classes from Subsonic (or other ORM tool) along with their repository classes in my .data project and my tests in the .test project. Apart from that, I use the main project as normal. Views in the Views folder, Models in the Models folder and so on.